Convolution of exponential and multivariate normal
Let $i=1,2,\dots,n$. For $t \geq 0$, I have a SDE of the form:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dX_{i,t}}{X_{i,t}} = \sigma_{i} dW_{i,t} + dJ_{t}
\end{equation}
where $W_{i}$ is a Wiener process, $J_{t}$ is "common" jump process with Poisson arrivals and gamma jump size, and $dW_{i,t}dW_{j,t} = \rho_{i,j}dt$. My goal is to get find the pdf via convolution.
Below is my attempt. Please any helpful feedback will be appreciated.
Let $f_{X}(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x} 1_{x \geq 0}$ where $X \in \mathbb{R}$, $\lambda > 0$ is a scalar and $g_Y(y) = (2\pi)^{-n/2} |\Sigma|^{1/2} \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(y-\mu)^{T} \Sigma^{-1} (y-\mu) \right\}$ where $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. The goal is to find $f * g (z)$.
So far I did the following:
\begin{align}
f * g (z) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda z} 1_{z \geq 0} (2\pi)^{-n/2} |\Sigma|^{-1/2} \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(y- z - \mu)^{T} \Sigma^{-1} (y- z - \mu)\right\} dz \\
&= \lambda (2\pi)^{-n/2} |\Sigma|^{-1/2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp\left\{-\lambda z -\frac{1}{2}(y- z - \mu)^{T} \Sigma^{-1} (y- z - \mu)\right\} dz \\
&= c \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp\left\{-\lambda z -\frac{1}{2}(y - z -\mu)^{T} \Sigma^{-1} (y - z -\mu)\right\} dz \\ 
&= c \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}(y-\mu)^{T} \Sigma^{-1} (y-\mu)\right\} \exp\left\{-\lambda z - \frac{1}{2}(z^{T}\Sigma^{-1}z - 2z^{T}\Sigma^{-1}y + 2z^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu) \right\} dz \\ 
&= c \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp\left\{-\lambda z - \frac{1}{2}(z^{T}\Sigma^{-1}z - 2z^{T}\Sigma^{-1}y + 2z^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu) \right\} dz
\end{align}
where $c = \lambda (2\pi)^{-n/2} |\Sigma|^{-1/2} \exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}(y-\mu)^{T} \Sigma^{-1} (y-\mu)\right\}$ and $|\cdot|$ is the determinant operator.
I'm stuck on the last step. I think it requires to complete the squares. Any help will be much appreciated.

What does the $e^{-\lambda x}$ notation mean in $f_{X}(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$? Is $\lambda$ a scalar or vector?

$\lambda$ is a scalar. Thanks for asking I will edit.

But $x$ is still an $n$-vector?

No. I corrected. Thanks.

The integral only makes sense if $z$ is a real scalar, but in that case $y-z$ amounts to subtracting a real scalar from a vector. That's not well-defined unless it's something like $y-z\mathbb{1}$, and at that point you're not doing a convolution in the usual sense. (And that's not really a shock: convolution is defined for functions on the same space, not for a scalar function and a vector function.)

@Semiclassical I have for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ a SDE $\frac{dX_{i,t}}{X_{i,t}} = \sigma_{i} dW_{i,t} + dJ_{t}$ where $dW_{i,t}dW_{j,t}=\rho_{i,j}dt$, $W_{i,t}$ and $J_{t}$ is a Wiener process for $i$ and $J_{t}$ is a "common" jump process with arrivals as Poisson and jump size as Gamma variate. My goal was to find the pdf, and I had the understanding to find the pdf via convolution. Is this incorrect?

I could not tell you, not being particularly versed in SDEs. Moreover, this seems like relevant context that should be presented in the question itself. (This also smacks of an XY problem.
